# How to build a table with a row split between two row headers

Tags: html, css, html-table

The following image is for illustration purposes only; I don't expect to win a Turner Prize.

- The top three `<th>` headers are `scope="col"`.
- The left three `<th>` headers are `scope="row"`.
- As you can see (circled in red); the `<td>` cells of row five are described easily by row one's col headers, but should also be described by **two** of the left row headers.

I am genuinely amazed by how difficult this is proving to be; I thought simply to use `rowspan="3"` on the header top left of the red circle, then `rowspan="2"` on the row five cells, continuing to introduce the header bottom left of the red circle with `rowspan="5"`, giving ten header rows, with the cells of row five being two rows deep, but no matter what I try it will not work. See snippet below image.

[image: My beautiful drawing of what I cannot create]

What am I doing wrong?

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>The table that hates me</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">col head 1</th>
      <th scope="col">col head 2</th>
      <th scope="col">col head 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">row head 1</th>
      <td>cell</td><td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" rowspan="3">row head 2<br>should be three rows deep</th>
      <td>cell</td><td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">cell should be two rows deep</td>
      <td rowspan="2">cell should be two rows deep</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" rowspan="5">row head 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- What have you tried? Everything I can think of.
- Have you searched? Yes; Google was at least as confused as I am.
- Is this a homework project and you're just lazy? No.

Please show me the table structure.

Comment: This is not possible with a single table, but you may include a table with 2 vertical cells in the left cell (colspan=7 in your drawing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Firefox renders your example as you want it to. Blink and WebKit don't though, which is where I assume you tested.

Also note that Blink IS making "cell should be two rows deep" span two rows, it's just giving one of the rows height of ~`0px`. So you can force those two rows to have a height. In the below I gave hardcoded `15px`. To make those rows more responsive instead of hardcoding, you can use script like `offsetHeight` or ResizeObserver to check the height of a nearby cell you want it to match, divide by 2, and set the two target rows to that height. Hacky and sucky, but might suffice for your use case?

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>The table that hates me</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">col head 1</th>
      <th scope="col">col head 2</th>
      <th scope="col">col head 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">row head 1</th>
      <td>cell</td><td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" rowspan="3">row head 2<br>should be three rows deep</th>
      <td>cell</td><td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>cell3</td><td>cell</td></tr>
    <tr style="height:15px;">
      <td rowspan="2">cell should be two rows deep</td>
      <td rowspan="2">cell should be two rows deep</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:15px;">
      <th scope="row" rowspan="5">row head 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The size (also height)  of table cells depends on their *contents*  and will dynamically change with the content. There is no height definition as "two cells high" for a cell. Just add content and it will get higher, or apply a fixed `height` and `overflow-y: visible` for that cell.

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}

.the_special_cell {
  height: 3em;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>The table that hates me</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">col head 1</th>
      <th scope="col">col head 2</th>
      <th scope="col">col head 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">row head 1</th>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" rowspan="3">row head 2<br>should be three rows deep</th>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="the_special_cell">cell should be two rows deep</td>
      <td rowspan="2">cell should be two rows deep</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" rowspan="5">row head 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```